# How can I use the Apache Commons CLI library to handle "complex" arguments?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, apache-commons-cli

An example might be where the arguments to the commandline are `-x`, `-y`, and `-z`. However, if `-z` is used, then it also requires `-a value` `-b value2`, and `-c value3`. to all be passed and present and there is an optional `-d value` argument.

I don't see any examples with any kind of complexity like this. Is there an example of how to set up "complex" argument sets where the value of an argument defines later arguments? Or is there a different method of parsing arguments that would be better suited to this?

Answer (score 0):

I think with commons-cli you can only do the simple parsing with the framework, it just does not provide advanced possibilities right now. You would then do additional checks like the ones you describe yourself as separate step after the initial parsing is done.